# How do I write the signature of a function that displays an error and exits the program?

Tags: rust

There are tons of articles on error handling in Rust, but they all seem to result in returning an error object causing a panic or something like that.

I want to check user input for an error, so I can't just pass it down the stack and I can't just panic (It's hardly user friendly)

Currently I'm using an empty `if let` with an `else` block to handle this, but it seems ugly and awkward. In the mountain of convenience methods in `Option` and `Result`, is there nothing that allows me to call a final method?

`unwrap_or_else` just complains that the closure return value is the wrong type.

```
use std::io::{stderr, Write};
use std::env;
use std::process::exit;

fn error_out(e: &str) {
    writeln!(&mut stderr(), "{}", e).expect(format!("Failed to print error: {}", e).as_str());
    exit(1);
}

fn main() {
    if let Some(filename) = env::args().nth(1) {} else {
        error_out("No filename provided");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the return type `!` to `error_out` to indicate that it doesn't return. Then its type doesn't matter and it is OK to call it in `unwrap_or_else`:

```
use std::process::exit;

fn error_out(e: &str) -> ! {
    writeln!(&mut stderr(), "{}", e).expect(format!("Failed to print error: {}", e).as_str());
    exit(1);
}

fn main() {
    let filename: String = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| error_out("No filename provided"));
    println!("{}", filename);
}
```